# How to pass request.user / user to message in Django

Tags: django

So I want to let a user message another user. I want the 'sender' field automatically to be 'request.user' and the receiver field to be the user whom the sender clicked on through their profile page.  How would I go about passing those into the form?

**matches.html**

```
<div class="container">

    <p>Username: {{ profile }}</p>
    <h5>Your Matches:</h5>
    {% for item in match %}
        <br>
        <p>Username: <br>{{ item.username}}</p>
        <img src="{{  item.photo.url  }}" width="300">
        <p>Bio: <br>{{ item.description }}</p>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

**forms.py/InstantMessageForm**

```
class InstantMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InstantMessage
        fields = ('receiver','sender','message')


        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(InstantMessageForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.receiver = cleaned_data['receiver']
            user.sender = cleaned_data['sender']
            user.message = cleaned_data['message']


            if commit:
                user.save()

            return user
```

**views.py/instant_message**

```
def instant_message(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstantMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('dating_app:home')

    else:
        form = InstantMessageForm()


    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'dating_app/instant_message_form.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class InstantMessage(models.Model):

    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    message = models.TextField()
```

class InstantMessage(models.Model):

```
receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
message = models.TextField()
```

**instant_message_form.py**

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}



<h1>Start chatting  now!</h1>




    <div class='container'>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'dating_app:instant_message' %}" >


            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form without the `sender` field:

```
class InstantMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InstantMessage
        fields = ('receiver', 'message')
```

Then in the view, you can inject the `request.user` as the `.sender` of `.instance` wrapped in the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def instant_message(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstantMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.sender = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('dating_app:home')
    else:
        form = InstantMessageForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/instant_message_form.html',context)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

In order to set the receiver, your url should for example contain the a primary key of the receiver. You can then remove the `receiver` from the form as well, and thus use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def instant_message(request, receiver_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstantMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.sender = request.user
            form.instance.receiver = get_object_or_404(get_user_mode(), pk=receiver_id)
            form.save()
            return redirect('dating_app:home')
    else:
        form = InstantMessageForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/instant_message_form.html',context)
```

You of course need then to alter the `urls.py` accordingly and the `action` url, such that it includes the primary key of the receiver.

Comment: How would I pass it to the template? I tried to do it but couldn't. I put my template up there.